# How to change the size of the off-heap in neo4j?

Tags: performance, memory, neo4j

Does anyone know which parameters can affect the size of the off-heap memory?
In neo4j documentation, they said that the size of the off-heap memory can be modified with the dbms.pagecache.memory parameter.
I tried changing the size of this parameter, but when I check the off-heap memory with jconsole, the size is always the same.
PS: I'm working with the free version of neo4j.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the 2.1.6 of the community edition

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j <= 2.1.x uses the so called [MMIO cache](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.8/configuration-caches.html#_file_buffer_cache) as first level cache. This basically uses mapped memory capabilities provided by the operating system. On Unix style OSes the file buffer cache is off heap on windows it's on heap. For a verbose description including the config settings refer to http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.8/configuration-caches.html#_file_buffer_cache.

In Neo4j 2.2 this cache layer's implementation was changed to the [page cache](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.3/configuration-caches.html#_file_buffer_cache). Page cache is off heap on all OSes. It's configuration has been reduced to just on setting:

```
dbms.pagecache.memory
```

So you've used a 2.2 config option on a 2.1 instance. So either use the set of options for 2.1 or do a upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So I tried to modify the file buffer cache with: `neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory`
`neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory`
`neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory`
`neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory`
`neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory`
I put this parameters in the neo4j.properties.
Although I change the size of this parameters, the size of the off-heap memory remained the same.
Is it normal? My Neo4j servers are on debian virtual machines.